# selecting rows in the last 5 minutes using unix time stamp

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

Iam trying to figure out whetere data was save to the db in the las 5 minutes.

```
SELECT COUNT(id), DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
FROM `table`
WHERE `timestamp` >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

`timestamp` is a unix timestamp (millisecs from 1970).

doesn't work, I get null`num_rows` instead of 0 and if I use

```
if (!isset($resultHistory->num_rows) || !$resultHistory->num_rows)
```

to do actions, the code does not enter the loop..

I also tried

```
SELECT COUNT(id), DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
    FROM `table`
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current_timestamp returns the current date as a SQL TIMESTAMP, not a UNIX timestamp, so you'd have to convert using the [unix_timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), from_unixtime(`timestamp` / 1000, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
FROM `table`
WHERE `timestamp` >= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) * 1000
```

EDIT:

As your `timestamp` column contains unix time, you're also going to have to use [from_unixtime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to format the date.

EDIT2:

In MySQL UNIX time is the number of seconds since epoch (1/1/70), so if your `timestamp` column contains the number of milliseconds, you'll have to divide by 1000 as well.

Comment: hi @beny23, thanks for the reply. I have tried that. I think somthing elese is the issue, I completly emptied the table, and still I get `$result->num_rows = 1` and when I fetch the object `$row = $result->fetch_object();` , I get null

Comment: @devmonster: I suspect that's a different question, have you tried the query directly in the MySQL command line tool?

Answer (score 2):

You could do like that :

```
SELECT COUNT(id), DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
FROM `table`
WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN (DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)) AND NOW()
```