# select time 5 minutes before now

Tags: php, mysql, vote

I'm currently writing a script for voting, and I need to know if the user voted in the last 5 minutes. If yes, next vote is forbidden.

How can I make a request for this?

This was my try:

```
WHERE time AFTER INTERVAL(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 5 MINUTES)
```

Comment: Does it work - Or it doe not work?

Comment: @EdHeal there was an error in the syntax

Comment: enduring a syntax error is a simple problem to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

Try that.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(id), from_unixtime(`timestamp` / 1000, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
FROM `table`
WHERE `timestamp` >= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) * 1000
```

Refer link below

[Already in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064516/selecting-rows-in-the-last-5-minutes-using-unix-time-stamp)

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
time < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$time = date('YmdHis', strtotime('-5 minutes', strtotime('now')));
"...WHERE time > '$time'"
```

Comment: In this case MySQL and PHP has to have the same timezone and everything.

Comment: MySQL and PHP should probably have the same timezone anyway, but this is the best scenario if the data in the `time` column was originally added by PHP, or if he want's to use the "5 minutes ago" value later in code or additional MySQL calls.