# Most view topic posted in last 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to retrive top 10 most viewed topic which are posted in last 24 hours. If the website gets less than 10 topics from last 24 hours it has to retrive the remaining most viewed topics from the previous day.

I stored the time in database in unix format and views are in integers. I want to know the sql query to fetch in the above manner.

```
$time_start = time(U);
$time_end = strtotime('-1 day', $time_start);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics where topic_active = 'Yes' and topic_type = 'topic' and topic_time BETWEEN $time_start and $time_end ORDER BY topic_views DESC LIMIT 10");
```

topic_time is the topic posted time stored in database in unix format like 1411657030

From the above query I can only fetch most viewed from last 24 hours if there is no topic post this will show blank. What can be the query to fetch the topic from previous day.

Comment: why not just do a `order by topic_time desc limit 10`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, if I do by order, most view will not comes up

Comment: A long, long time ago, we stopped using PHP's mysql_ API. Join us!

Comment: 24 hours is 86400 seconds. Does that help?

Comment: @Strawberry, yah I tried this before.

Comment: I think you have to explain a bit more about what topic_time actually means.

Comment: @Strawberry, I have added to my post 'topic_time is the topic posted time stored in database in unix format like 1411657030
'

Answer (score 0):

Use some thing like this and please let me know it that works

```
SELECT *, from_unixtime(topic_time / 1000, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') FROM topics
WHERE topic_time >= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 DAY) * 1000
```

Please check the following link

[selecting rows in the last 5 minutes using unix time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064516/selecting-rows-in-the-last-5-minutes-using-unix-time-stamp)

Comment: But how is it sorting the most view on top ?? its giving blank result.

Comment: You mean result is null or it is not sorting

Comment: what is your topic_time type is it timestamp?

Comment: Can you please check this link it may helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064516/selecting-rows-in-the-last-5-minutes-using-unix-time-stamp

Comment: I check that.. its differnt then my needs. I need the most viewed in last interval.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work...

```
SELECT *
     , 1 x 
  FROM topics 
 WHERE topic_active = 'Yes'
   AND topic_type = 'topic' 
   AND topic_created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-86400
 UNION 
SELECT *
     , 2
  FROM topics 
 WHERE topic_active = 'Yes'
   AND topic_type = 'topic' 
   AND topic_created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-172800
 ORDER 
    BY x
     , topic_views 
 LIMIT 10;
```